# Execute a file within a Python 3.x script and keep variables callable

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qt-designer

i did not find a way to keep variables defined/callable in another python.py file
after using "exec".

this is something i do using pyqt:
i want to execute a larger piece of code and
so i use "exec" in order to keep my  "gui program" seperated from my "calcuation program"

```
...gui. stuff...

if self.checkbox.checkState(): #"checkbox" = label of a checkboy in QTDesigner
        x=14

    exec(open("./calculation_where_x_used.py").read()) 

def onClose(self): # this is a button on my gui. labelled "Close"
    print("bye")
    self.close()
```

when i run this after checking a checkbox in the gui. the code does what it should do but all kind of matrices and variables which are defined in "calculation_where_x_used.py" aren´t callable through the shell anymore...

How can i fix this? PS: I Use Spyder as and Python 3.3

Comment: Have you tried passing globals() to exec?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `import` statement? That's the more idiomatic way to use code in separate files.

Answer (score 1):

Um... ick?

Don't (ab)use eval for this; turn your calculation code into a module, import and call it. Have it return the result values - problem solved.

Comment: how do i pass globals()?

Comment: @user2956831: explicitly! Globals are usually a bad idea.

Comment: how can i pass all the variables from the exec() ?

Comment: this is very strange, even if i make a matrix global that is used with the numpy module, i can not call it from the shell after running the function `from calculation_where_x_used.py import func`

Comment: Try `from calculation_where_x_used import func` (no .py), stop using globals, and in the worst case try `calculation_where_x_used.myglobalvar`.

Comment: `from calculation_where_x_used import func` works but all definitions and variables do not become global i do not understand `calculation_where_x_used.myglobalvar`

Comment: @user2956831: if `myglobalvar` is defined as a global _inside the module_, then you can access it from the main program by referring to it as `mymodule.myglobalvar`. Better yet, _stop using global variables_.